# Recursive approach of longest common subsequence

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recursion

I tried to solve Longest common subsequence problem using recursion, however as I later discovered, my thinking approach was wrong.

I took 2 strings say s1 and s2 with lengths l1 and l2, s1="ABDEH" s2="AEBFH". I created a decision tree.

My reasoning was that if s1[l1-1]==s2[l2-1] then I have 2 choices: to include or not to include in my subsequence. I reasoned this because I might have a longer subsequence that doesn't include this particular letter.

Now when s1[l1-1]!=s2[l2-1], then I had to select a string say s2, and search for s1[l1-1] in s2. And if I don't get it, then I would just have the choice of not including it.

I know I'm wrong in thinking that there are 2 choices when s1[l1-1]==s2[l1-1]. Also that there should be 2 choices when s1[l1-1]!=s2[l1-1].

I know my approach was very wrong. But I'm trying to improve my logic. So I know what I should have thought in place of what I did, but I don't know how to get to that logic from where I am now.

Sorry if the question sounds abstract.

Edit: Probably had this reasoning because I was thinking of how a knapsack problem works. There are 2 choices there when an element is eligible to be included in the knapsack.

Comment: If s1[l1-1]==s2[l2-1], technically there are two choices. However, you are always better off at picking both of them into the solution since including them will either increase the size of the subsequence of keep it the same. So the other choice doesn't matter.

Comment: When s1[l1-1]!=s2[l1-1], the two choices are 1. s1[l1-1] is not the part of the longest common subsequence 2. s2[l1-1] is not the part of the longest common subsequence. They both can not be the part since they are not equal.